# Testing app deployed on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using JMeter to create 100 simultaenous threads in an infinite loop. I use the DNS of the Elastic BS that Amazon gave me.  I have Min Instances set to 5 and Max = 5. Will this just magically work without me having to worry about internal IP addresses and have the load distributed evenly between all inistances?
What has me thinking is that I stumbled on this link in my research .
http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/jmeter-amazon-ec2-load-balancing-elb-td529294.html

Answer (score 0):

yes  - it should do. If you are testing you should be able to mimic the experience of the guy in the post and find out.